# Specify number of bits in binary conversion

Tags: java

I'm trying to store a number as a binary string in an array with specific length of 4 bits.
For example, if I need to store 0 with four bits I need a string like "0000".

```
For 1  -> "0001".
For 2  -> "0010".
For 3  -> "0011".
For 15 -> "1111".
```

How to do this?
And how can I store each character in an array with a length of 4?

Comment: I once needed a thing like this. I just calculated the binary using `Integer.toBinaryString()` and then filled up the remaining 0s by a custom method. Now, to store each character in an array, you can use `toCharArray()`

Comment: So should I use char array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet will do the trick:

```
String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));
```

that is:

- Integer.toBinaryString(i) will print the value of i as a binary
- String.format will format that result adding left-zeros until you get a 4 bits string...

## Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0'));
}
```